# UML: Sequence diagram for nested method

Tags: c#, uml

I have a clarification on drawing the UML sequence diagram for nested method. May I ask if the following diagram is right?

**Code (C#):**

```
Alpha alpha = new Alpha();
Beta beta = new Beta();
Random rs = new Random();

// Alpha has a method Push() and Beta has a method Colour()
alpha.Push(beta.Colour(rs));
```

**UML sequence diagram:**

[image: Sequence Diagram]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is not that, each arrow starts from the caller and arrives at the called, and in your case a return value is used as argument. The message is the applied operation with possible arguments

Supposing all is made from *Main*

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. So Main here is any class that encapsulates the instances and methods (alpha, beta, Push(), Colour()) right?

Comment: @SY yes I used Main as the class having you all your code, you did not said where it is

Comment: @GeertBellekens no reason at all (except a big headache I still have since days), all must be synchronous of course, corrected

Comment: It looks a bit weird that your lifelines for classes `Alpha` and `Beta` are cut up like that. It makes it seem like you create and destroy 2 instances of each class... not sure if that's correct